# Sharepoint Webservice not filtering Data

Tags: web-services, filter, caml

**Working Version**

Issue: I am querying SharePoint using SP CAML Query Helper. Using SPCQH I am able to retrieve one order. The query works.

Once I add the query to my Biztalk solution the query below does not work. It return all records in the list. Is there a critical piece of data that I am missing?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Body>
            <GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
                <listName>Orders</listName>
                <viewName />
                <query>
                    <Query xmlns="">
                        <Where>
                            <Or>
                                <Eq>
                                    <FieldRef Name="FAC_OrderNumber" />
                                    <Value Type="Text">12095-1</Value>
                                </Eq>
                                <Eq>
                                    <FieldRef Name="FAC_Related_Order" />
                                    <Value Type="Text">12095-1</Value>
                                </Eq>
                            </Or>
                        </Where>
                    </Query>
                </query>
                <viewFields>
                    <ViewFields xmlns="" />
                </viewFields>
                <rowLimit />
                <queryOptions>
                    <QueryOptions xmlns="">
                        <IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
                    </QueryOptions>
                </queryOptions>
                <webID />
            </GetListItems>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Version that Does not work

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <ns0:GetListItems xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/" xmlns:ns1="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/types/">
            <ns0:listName>Orders</ns0:listName>
            <ns0:viewName/>
            <query>
                <Query>
                    <Where>
                        <Or>
                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name="FAC_OrderNumber"/>
                                <Value Type="Text">12095-1</Value>
                            </Eq>
                            <Eq>
                                <FieldRef Name="FAC_Related_Order"/>
                                <Value Type="Text">12095-1</Value>
                            </Eq>
                        </Or>
                    </Where>
                </Query>
            </query>
            <viewFields>
                <ViewFields/>
            </viewFields>
            <ns0:rowLimit/>
            <queryOptions>
                <QueryOptions>
                    <IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
                </QueryOptions>
            </queryOptions>
            <ns0:webID/>
        </ns0:GetListItems>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```